# Building / Publishing Artifacts with Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am trying to learn the *basics* of building with Visual Studio Online.

I have worked through the basic instructions and watched the video [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/vs/define-build).

As in the video, I am using a simple web application project.  What gets copied to the artifacts folder is the contents of the bin folder.  What I am trying to have copied to the artifacts folder is everything for the site (such as the bin folder contents, web.config, etc).  I *think* I am supposed to specify the path in the Contents text box for the Publish Build Artifacts step but I have tried every combination but nothing is ever copied.  What is the *secret* to doing this?

Comment: Is this a website or a web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contents specify minimatch pattern filters (one on each line) that you want to apply to the list of files to be copied. For example:

** copies all files in the root folder.

**\ * copies all files in the root folder and all files in all sub-folders.

**\ bin copies files in any sub-folder named bin.

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/build/publish-build-artifacts

If you want to manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext, you can check this article: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/

Comment: Perhaps this is mentioned somewhere in the resources you referenced, but ** is the root folder, not of the solution you are building but rather the team project in which the solution you are building resides.  Once I discovered this, I was able to provide the paths to the files I wanted to include in the publish artifact step.  At any rate, the references you provided helped lead me down the correct path so I have marked your answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you do not want to copy everything in your web project.  If you have a publish profile defined for your web project, you can add the following settings to the Visual Studio Build step in VSO:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=PublishProfileName
```

This way, you can use the publish profile settings for compiling views and transforming web.config.  The output path is specified in the publish profile (e.g. C:\Publish) and this path can be used as inputs to subsequent VSO Build steps.

Comment: Problem with this is, Microsoft discourages you from putting Publish profiles in your source code because they contain sensitive data. Not that this is not correct, but recommend finding a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue couldn't figure out how to get just the contents that I would normally get if I were to set up a publish profile and published via FTP for example (using the publish settings didn't work for me, it complain about publish directory don't exist).

Through trial and error, I did this...

[image: Visual Studio Online Team Services Copy Publish Artifact Settings]